# How do I replace the None values in this list?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to replace the blank spaces or None values from this 2-d list

```
chess_board = [ [rook_3, knight_3, bishop_3, queen_2, king_2, bishop_4, knight_4, rook_4],
                [pawn_9, pawn_10, pawn_11, pawn_12, pawn_13, pawn_14, pawn_15, pawn_16],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [pawn_1, pawn_2, pawn_3, pawn_4, pawn_5, pawn_6, pawn_7, pawn_8],
                [rook_1, knight_1, bishop_1, queen_1, king_1, bishop_2, knight_2, rook_2]
               ]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Test for truthiness in a boolean context with a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in chess_board if i]
```

---

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], [], [3, 4]]
>>> [i for i in x if i]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>>
```